# Application asks to list last 3 employers- would this be an acceptable way to answer the question?

Tags: applications

So a job application asks for the last three employers. I have one previous job that is relevant to my career that I held last year. I would like to avoid a particular job I held 2 years ago and not include it on the application. I currently do Uber and Lyft on the side. Would I be able to list Uber and Lyft as 2 of the 3 last employers?

I was let go from the job I’m trying to avoid. It won’t show up on a background check. School districts only run background checks on criminal history. I didn’t put this job on my last job application and it was never brought up.

Comment: Are Uber and Lyft in any way connected to the field of job you are applying for? Any more importantly why do you want to avoid the job from 2 years back?

Comment: Are you *able* to?  Sure.  You can do whatever you want.  Will it help or hurt your chances of getting the job?  We can't know that.  Some employers might toss you out for it while others might not care at all.

Comment: Read your contracts with Uber and Lyft.  You'll find that you're not employed by either.

Comment: Suppose you do omit the job; how would you explain the gap in your CV?

Answer (score 2):

I'd include your previous job on your resume, and find a way of explaining that experience in a way that results in a positive outcome for you.  There's plenty of advice out on the internet about how to explain the fact that you were let go - it's a challenge that many people go through and it's certainly not a blocker for employment (within reason).

Uber and Lyft are just what you say (time/money filling jobs), and the interviewer will most probably seem them as such (you being temporarily out of work and needing the extra cash).

You can mention these if you like, but I'd suggest sticking with the relevant job history and having a good explanation for you being let go before.